# How do I get standard posts to open up in their own template when using get_template_part()?

Tags: theme-development, post-formats, get-template-part

It seems to me that twentyelven opens standard single posts using the file `content-single.php` yet when I try the same code and files they open for me in `content.php`

here's the code I have in index.php

`<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>`

... then I have two files `content.php` and `content-single.php`

Standard posts are opening up in content.php not content-single.php

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually nothing to fix.

In Twenty Eleven, this is used in `index.php`:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

...and this is used in `single.php`:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
```

The design intent here is that all posts, regardless of post format, will display the same in single-post view, but that posts with defined post formats will have a custom display in archive indexes.

If you have a *different* design intent - e.g. you want to use the post-format custom display in the single-post view, simply change the call in `single.php` from this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
```

...to this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

Likewise, if you want to call `content-single.php` from within `index.php`, you'd need to change the call the other way around, perhaps like so:

```
if ( get_post_format() ) {
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );
}
```

Another approach:

```
$postformat = ( get_post_format() ? get_post_format() : 'single' );
get_template_part( 'content', $postformat );
```

Either should result in the same thing.

Comment: I missed the fact that there was a single.php file ... when I saw the content-single.php file I jumped to the conclusion that get_post_format() defaulted to 'standard'; ( which would have seemed more intuitive to me; but I'm sure I'll see the logic when I get to use it more) .... but by the looks of it it defaults to false, which is why I think I'll need your suggestion of `if ( get_post_format() ) ... etc ...` to do what I was trying to do. Thanks